# Apollo client v3 not caching query results with useQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am using `apollo v3` with a `create-react app`. I fire a query with `useQuery` and expect results to be cached, but they are not.

In my `App.jsx`, I have:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: `${api}/graphql`,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  })
```

I wrap my app with the `ApolloProvider`.

I have a provider that uses this `graphql` query to fetch a list of users:

```
const USERS_QUERY = gql`
  query GetUsers {
    users {
      id
      email
      fullName
    }
  }
`
```

The query works, when I inspect the apollo tab in chrome devtools, I see nothing in the cache section.

My questions:

1. Why are the results not cached if I am using the `useQuery` from `@apollo/client`?

`const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(USERS_QUERY)`

I thought results should be cached automatically.

2. I also tried to add a type policy:

   ```
   cache: new InMemoryCache({
      typePolicies: {
        Users: {
          keyFields: ['id']
        }
      }
    })
   ```

But I think I use this if I want to normalise with a different key the cache, or if I want to decide how to merge new data by myself. But first I need to have the data in my cache

Comment: how did you fix this @AlbertMunichMar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is because your query does not have any input arguments / variables, so the cache does not know which item to get from the cache when the query is called again. From what I understand, the cache is only used when a specific piece of data is looked for with an ID; otherwise, if it is a generic query, the data might have changed and so is not cached.